# Cannot install MySql Server

Tags: mysql, windows-installer

After more than a dozen tries, I have been unable to install MySql Server (mysql-5.5.37-win32.msi) on my Windows XP machine. I have Googled this extensively and also looked at all related answers in Stackoverflow, but nothing has worked so far. Here is what happens-

I run the installer as follows-

1. "Typical" install
2. "Standard Configuration" (since this is a fresh install)
3. "Install as Windows Service", Service Name = MySql
4. "Modify security settings" checkbox checked. I supply a root password and confirm
5. I say "Execute" and it goes thru' 4 steps and fails in the last step. It successfully does "Prepare Configuration", "Write Configuration" and "Start Service", and fails on "Apply Security Settings". It puts up a message box with the following error-

Error nr. 1045
Access denied for 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Was MySQL already installed on the PC? It looks like the database folder is not empty. You can find the dir in my.ini in the MySQL folder.

Comment: Yes, it was installed earlier (as I said I tried this more than a dozen times).I found from other posts that the MySql folder has to be removed to be rid of the old password. So, each time I tried to re-install it, I removed the old folder after uninstalling the program, and then did the new install. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: try to install it without a root password and add the password later

Comment: I tried that as well, and it still failed. Finally, I did the install with a different version-  a server + client all-in-one package. That worked. Thanks.